# Show X inside the body tag of a php file in case the screen size is smaller than Y

Tags: php, javascript, css, mobile, drop-down-menu

I need to adapt my template to mobile versions, without creating different page files for each case, or subsites. I think the easiest way to do that is to change the css files to "rearrange" some elements.

So this is what I´ve done so far:

- I´m working with php.
- I´ve made use of @media queries, adding inside the `<head>` this:   `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 700px)" href="/css/smartphones.css" />`, so it will call the smartphones.css file each time the users access the site with a small device.
- Everything goes kinda smoothly, up until now, when I decided to adapt the dropdown menu.
  I´ve got a dropdown menu in pure css, that gets activated on mouse over. I use :hover to get the menu to actually drop down.

**I want to replace that big dropdown menu with many items (horizontally and vertically), to a single button, that *onclick* will dropdown, and show just a couple of things.**

In order to do that I need to adapt my php page file to hidden the entire dropdown menu and show the "mini-onclick" dropdown menu instead. And here is what I don´t know how to do it.

I need some -javascript I guess- inside my body tag (as the menu appears inside the body) to say something like:

**IF the screen is less than 700px, show this XXXX code. ELSE keep going with the rest of the page.**

I´m planning to hide the normal dropdown menu using css inside the smartphones.css file, but don´t know how to show the special dropdown menu instead.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! THANKS!

Rosamunda

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes, that´s how I changed the css file (media="only screen and (max-width: 700px)"), but how can I just add a specific line inside the body file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `User-Agent` HTTP header in PHP to determine if smartphone-relevant code should be generated instead of normal code.

You could also get screen properties via the `screen` object, and if it's a smartphone, attach the dropdown state to the `onclick` event and if not to the `onmouseover` event.

That's pretty simple. You just change your CSS from `someclass:hover` to `someclass.hoverstate` and when the dropdown needs to be triggered, you add the `hoverstate` class to the target element.